# Differentiating between Google Analytics Tracking of Facebook App and Web App

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have a web app at www.mydomain.com/webapp and its set up with Google Analytics.  I create a facebook app at apps.facebook.com/webapp and iframe in the above url.

Is there a way to distinguish activity of users on facebook from users on mydomain?

Thanks for any help and direction you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to determine that your page is displayed in an iframe – but that would also be true if maybe other sites embedded your page.

A better way would be to check for the `[signed_request][1]` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe. (If you were paranoid about someone “faking” that, you could also *verify* the signed_request.)

Once you figured out *that* your page was actually loaded inside Facebook, it should be easy to execute the appropriate JS code to send that info to Analytics.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I just figured I was missing something and that maybe GA and Facebook had come up with a way to do this fairly seamlessly.  Thanks for your answer.  I'll give it a go!